# How to disable the back and forward mouse buttons in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I have a 5 button Microsoft mouse. I always press acidentally the navigation buttons, and I want to disable them without using the software that came with the mouse. Is it possible? (Without modifying the hardware?)

Comment: if you don't want to use "the software that came with the mouse", uninstall the driver and it will be treated like a regular 2 button mouse.

Comment: It doesn't work like that on my G5, unfortunately - without setpoint the mouse becomes quite unconfigurable.

Comment: @Molly, I never installed the software that came with the mouse. A HID compliant mouse can have more than 3 working buttons, without specific drivers

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to install the mouse's software? You can probably get a very similar Microsoft mouse without the extra buttons, too. That would be the easiest way. The nice thing about using the software though is that you can choose different settings for different apps, in case you do occasionally want to actually use the buttons.

Comment: The main problem I have with setpoint is it's incredibly slow! Sure, that's just the config UI, but it calls their programming skills into question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try using AutoHotKey, but 5 button mice aren't always consistent. If yours IS, try:

```
XButton1::
XButton2::
Return
```

Which should disable both. You could give either functionality you actually find useful with the software, as well.

Comment: http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: I'm a strong believer in "Just Google it" :)

Answer (score 1):

What options do you have when you go to **Control Panel > Mouse**?

I haven't got Windows 7 so I can't double check, but if it's recognising the extra buttons you should have options to disable them on the dialog.

Comment: For me, there are no extra options for the additional buttons (Win7 Enterprise)